# Display a notification that an item was successfully deleted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The site has a button for deleting an element (one element is deleted per button click).

Timing: the user presses the delete button -> a window opens with a warning and two buttons: cancel and confirm -> when the confirm button is pressed, the deletion process begins, which is accompanied by a scroll wheel. After deletion, the window closes and you can continue to work on the site.

I would like to display a notification after the window is closed that the item was removed successfully. Tell me how can I do it.

```
export function Delete() {
  const [alertShown, setAlertShown] = useState(false);
  const [alertLoading, setAlertLoading] = useState(false);

  const onNo = () => {
    setAlertShown(false);
  };

  const onYes = async () => {
      setAlertLoading(true);
      await deleteItem();
      setAlertShown(false);
      setAlertLoading(false);
  };

  
  return <ButtonGroup >
            <div onClick={() => setAlertShown(true)}>
                  <DeleteForeverIcon/>
            </div>

            {alertShown && (
                <Dialog open={onYes}>

                    {alertLoading 
                        ? <div ><Spinner/></div>
        
                        : <DialogActions >
                            <Button  color="error" onClick={onNo}>Cancel</Button >
                            <Button   onClick={onYes}>Confirm </Button >
                          </DialogActions>}                   
                </Dialog>
                )}
    </ButtonGroup>
}
```

Comment: Where do you want to show the notification? Do you want to have a notification in a short period of time only? If you're still exploring options, you can try this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-toastify

Comment: @NickVu At the moment, it doesn’t matter to me where this notification will be on the screen. While I would like to understand the principle of how to do this. The delete window appears in the center of the screen, it would probably be nice to place the notification in the center.  By time: yes, so that the notification pops up for no more than five seconds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest approach to implement notification is using `setTimeout`. You can try the below code snippet

```
export function Delete() {
  const [alertShown, setAlertShown] = useState(false);
  const [alertLoading, setAlertLoading] = useState(false);
  const [notificationShown, setNotificationShown] = useState(false);

  const onNo = () => {
    setAlertShown(false);
  };

  const onYes = async () => {
    setAlertLoading(true);
    await deleteItem();
    setAlertShown(false);
    setAlertLoading(false);
    //open the notification
    setNotificationShown(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNotificationShown(false);
    }, 5000); //automatically close the notification after 5 seconds
  };

  return (
    <ButtonGroup>
      {notificationShown && <span>The item was removed successfully</span>}
      <div onClick={() => setAlertShown(true)}>
        <DeleteForeverIcon />
      </div>
      {alertShown && (
        <Dialog open={onYes}>
          {alertLoading ? (
            <div>
              <Spinner />
            </div>
          ) : (
            <DialogActions>
              <Button color="error" onClick={onNo}>
                Cancel
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={onYes}>Confirm </Button>
            </DialogActions>
          )}
        </Dialog>
      )}
    </ButtonGroup>
  );
}
```

[The sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wave-ul207d?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: ahh I make a small syntax mistake in state, I just use your sandbox to update the code, could you verify it again? @Paul

Comment: Your code sandbox is empty though, are you sharing the correct one? @Paul

Comment: it's not empty, take a look at the icon in the top left corner

Comment: You can try this updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/autumn-water-y2g5v2, @Paul

Comment: Tell me why if I use await deleteItem({}, firestoreDummy) - everything works fine, but if I use await deleteItem( item, firestore, urlParams) in my working code - then the notification popup does not appear

Comment: I guess the problem is from `deleteItem` itself. It has an error, so that's why it never runs the notification. Side note, `await` never returns errors obviously, so you can add `catch(error)` to see which error you get. https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-wave-ul207d?file=/src/App.js:1871-2311 @Paul

Comment: It's amazing, but there are no errors. Are there any other options to solve this problem?

Comment: Hmm that's weird, could you try putting `setNotificationShown` before `await deleteItem`? @Paul

Comment: The bottom line is, as I noticed that when using await deleteItem(item, firestore, urlParams), notificationShown does not switch to true

Comment: i did  setNotificationShown before await deleteItem. Nothing not change

Comment: Hmm, could you share the full code on sandbox? I can try to find the true rootcause from that. @Paul

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't even know how to post my full code yet. Since the whole difficulty is that it is connected to the firestore. I will think and write to you later